# Realize a gui in ruby

Tags: ruby, user-interface

This is my first try to use a "real" GUI instead of yad.

I have built a gui in glade [there](https://tagmycode.com/snippet/3988/latexcv-glade#.VetFxLMx1c8).

I have to set the variables @jobtitle, @proactive, @company, @contact_sex, @contact and @emailaddress.

The content of "entry1" should go to @jobtitle.

@proactive should contain "yes" or "no" depending on "radiobutton1" or "radiobutton2".

"entry2" should go to @company.

@contact_sex should contain "male", "female" or "unknown" depending on "radiobutton 3-5".

@contact should contain "entry3"

And @emailaddress should contain "entry4"
"button1" is the launcher button.

Maybe anyone knows, how i can launch the gui and route the contents to the right variables?

Comment: Have you worked through the tutorials on Visual Ruby? http://visualruby.net/site/Quick%20Start.html

Comment: Your link isn't responding. Please don't use links to refer to anything important to your question. Links die (or don't respond) resulting in a question that makes no sense to those trying to help you, or to those searching for a similar question and answer. Also, please read through the documentation for formatting questions. Formatting your question in the common-look of other Stack Overflow questions makes it easier for us to read what you've provided, which speeds up our answers.